# Separate an NSString into NSArrau using Regular expression

Tags: nsstring, substring, nsregularexpression

I am trying to Separate an NSString into NSArray. I always used 'componentsSeparatedByString' to separate an NSString. But this method only get single separator also without any conditions. I want to separate string from "dot + space", "dot + newline", "dot + empty", "!" and "?". I am sure this could be done with regular expression but don't know how :D. I have never used regular expression before.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following hope it will work for you

NSString *strTest = @"a.b+c";

```
NSLog(@"seperated  %@", [strTest componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".+"]]);
```